# Sorting by a Date column in Datatables.net

Tags: asp.net, sorting, date, datatables

I can't seem to figure this out to get my date columns sorting properly. I've been using this as a reference https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18. I'm using asp.net with master pages.

I'm including in the following order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Assets/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

On the master page I have a function that I pass in the table ID and the columns I want to be printable to format a datatable on a content page which works fine for creating my datatables.

```
function formatDatatable(id, printableColumns) {
                $(id).DataTable({
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "lengthMenu": [
                        [10, 25, 50, -1],
                        [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                    ],
                    responsive: {
                        breakpoints: [
                            { name: 'desktop', width: Infinity },
                            { name: 'tablet', width: 1024 },
                            { name: 'fablet', width: 768 },
                            { name: 'phone', width: 480 }
                        ]
                    },
                    language: {
                        search: "_INPUT_",
                        searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
                    },
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy',
                        {
                            extend: 'excel',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: printableColumns
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'pdf',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: printableColumns
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'print',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: printableColumns
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
```

Also, on the master page I have the following code:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    console.log(moment('Dec 1 2019 12:00AM', 'MMM d YYYY hh:mma').isValid()); //validates to true
                    $.fn.dataTable.moment('MMM d YYYY hh:mma');
                });
```

}

And finally, the last function that I think is needed. I have tried adding this within the $(document).ready and outside it with the same result. I have added some logs and it will print test1 and test2 on load of datatable but it will not create any logs after the tables has been formated and I try to sort a column.

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment = function (format, locale) {
                    console.log("test1");
                    var types = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type;

                    // Add type detection
                    types.detect.unshift(function (d) {
                        console.log("test2");
                        return moment(d, format, locale, true).isValid() ?
                            'moment-' + format :
                            null;
                    });

                    // Add sorting method - use an integer for the sorting
                    types.order['moment-' + format + '-pre'] = function (d) {
                        console.log("test3");
                        return moment(d, format, locale, true).unix();
                    };
                };
```

Here are some of the dates within the table that I am trying to sort: Dec 1 2019 12:00AM, Jan 2 2020 3:58AM, Jan 1 2023 11:59PM

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: I simply add a hidden `<span class="d-none">yyyymmdd</span>` in the column with the correct sort format. That always works

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer you last week. I tried this implementation in my c# and it seems to solve my issues. Will have to do some further testing this week and if all as well I will submit my answer with what I did exactly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice of VDWWD in the comments above. I updated to return the hidden span with my data rather than using moment js that was giving me lots of issues.

First I created a function that recieves a nullable datetime:

```
public static string createDateColumnSpan(DateTime? date)
    {
        //if there is a date, format it
        if(date != null)
        {
            return "<span class='d-none'>" + Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + "</span>";
        }
        //else return empty string
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

In my linq queries I was able to call the function like so:

```
//get a list of events
var eventList = (from e in db.Events orderby e.DueDate select new
                {
                    e.ID,
                    e.DueDate
                }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
                {
                    x.ID,
                    DueDate = createDateColumnSpan(x.DueDate) + x.DueDate.ToString(),
                });
```

After this the column sorted properly client side with datatables.net